# Error [Parameter 0 of constructor] while trying to override functions inside NamingProxy

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am attempting to customize some functions inside NamingProxy, so that can exclude sepecific servers, which also need to regester into nacos.

But facing some issues:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.gof.springcloud.loadbalancer.CustomNamingProxy required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
```

Custom Codes are as following:

CustomNamingProxy

```
public class CustomNamingProxy extends NamingProxy {

    public CustomNamingProxy(String namespaceId, String endpoint, String serverList, Properties properties) {
        super(namespaceId, endpoint, serverList, properties);
    }

    @Override
    public String reqApi(String api, Map<String, String> params, Map<String, String> body, String method)
            throws NacosException {
        return reqApi(api, params, body, getMyServerList(), method);
    }

    private List<String> getMyServerList() {
        // TODO
        return null;
    }
}
```

SpringBootApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableCaching
@ComponentScan(includeFilters  = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = { NamingProxy.class }) })
public class Gateway9111_App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Gateway9111_App.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't return any service list.  Firstly, fill the `// TODO` line

```
private List<String> getMyServerList() {
        // TODO
        return null;
}
```